# Installing AWS elasticsearch plugin on Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have very basic knowledge of Linux (Ubuntu in this case).
I am trying to install elasticsearch, and get it to point where I am comfortable with it, and that I can use it with my application.

I am followign tutorials from elasticsearch website, and I am stuck at the start. I have Ubuntu 32bit EC2 instance running. I SSH-ed to it. I am ready to install elasticsearch.

Here are the commands from [elasticsearch tutorial](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/elasticsearch-on-ec2/)

```
$ wget http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.19.0.zip
$ sudo unzip elasticsearch-0.19.0.zip -d /usr/local/elasticsearch
$ cd /usr/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.19.0
$ sudo bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/1.4.0
```

I manage to install it (bear in mind that I learn Ubuntu commands as I go along)

The last command is giving me a headache. It always gives this error:

```
bin/plugin: 31: exec: -Xmx64m: not found
```

For a moment i hoped it was issue that I use 64 bit Ubuntu. So I quickly spun up 32bit, with same result and same error message. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing Java.

This command took care of that problem:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```